# Есть ли стандартный макрос для вычисление компилятора программы на С?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc

Хочу исполнить раздельную компиляцию через использование условных директив.

Например, если используется компилятор Visual Studio (по-моему Intel), то выполняется следующий код, иначе, если компилятор gcc, то другой код.

Саму реализацию я знаю. Мне важно узнать какой макрос используется для определения компилятора Visual Studio. На просторах интернета я нашел макрос __ **MINGW32** __, но он (компилятор) не используется в VS.

Comment: `_MSC_VER` например? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/predef/blob/develop/include/boost/predef/compiler/visualc.h

Answer (score 1):

Нет, у каждого компилятора есть свой макрос да ещё может меняться от версии к версии, можно конечно под каждый необходимый вручную их узнать, но есть более проверенный способ https://github.com/boostorg/predef/blob/develop/doc/predef.adoc

Пример

```
#include <boost/predef.h>
#include <iostream>

#if BOOST_COMP_GNUC
  #if BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= BOOST_VERSION_NUMBER(4,0,0)
    const char * the_compiler = "GNU GCC, of at least version 4."
  #else
    const char * the_compiler = "GNU GCC, less than version 4."
  #endif
#else
  const char * the_compiler = "Not GNU GCC."
#endif

int main()
{
  std::cout << the_compiler << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Автора вопроса интересует Си. Ваше решение — исключительно для Сиплюсплюса. Это разные языки. И разные компиляторы, если уж говорим о gcc.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Конкретно эта часть буста работает исключительно за счет С препроцессора и может использоваться в C++, C, Objective C, and Objective C++.

Comment: @user7860670 этот код элементарно не компилируется (скорее всего, не препроцессится) с помощью `cc`. Так что нет, в **GCC** использоваться не может.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Если у вас возникают какие-то проблемы с использованием этой библиотеки в gcc, то составьте [mcve] и отправьте его в багтрекер boost.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev этот код элементарно содержит стримы и не может компилится из-за этого на С, просто убери зависимость, не думал что нужно объяснять такие банальности

Comment: @Arenoros нет. Посмотри на ошибки, выдаваемые `cc`.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev ты так рофлишь или что? у C и C++ один и тот же препроцессор,